# ping not working for google alone

Tags: networking, dns

one of my friend changed some **network config** in my laptop at home, He said he tried **something related to block a website(he tested it with www.google.com**).Now `www.google.com` not loading . Even he dont no what to do now .

Now Everytime when i try `www.google.com` in  chrome browser its saying , **could't connect to www.google.com**,i tried it even with different browsers,but same result.But not problems with other domain names.

Instead of domain name i am using the the **ip address** of `www.google.com` ,That time it's loading

But no problem in other google websites like www.google.co.in , www.google.co.uk , www.gmail.com ,

i guess the problem is in dns settings .
But i am not familier  with networking .

```
Details of file /etc/hosts

127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   karthi-Vostro-1550
192.168.1.1 www.google.com

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters

**this is the result of nslookup**

Server:     127.0.1.1
Address:    127.0.1.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   www.google.com
Address: 74.125.236.180
Name:   www.google.com
Address: 74.125.236.178
Name:   www.google.com
Address: 74.125.236.177
Name:   www.google.com
Address: 74.125.236.179
Name:   www.google.com
Address: 74.125.236.176
```

**result of Ping www.google.com - 100 % packet loss**

My friend changed the config in my home.  Now i am in college .The same problem is happening in my college too . But there is a difference

*In home* 
When i enter into a website that enabled google adsense then the google chrome asking username and password . But even though that page is loading .

*In college* 
Chrome not asking for any username or password . But www.google.com not loading

If any further details needed i am ready to give

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your friend added a mapping for`www.google.com` to `/etc/hosts` which points to an IP address in the private IPv4 network address space corresponding to the `192.168.0.0/16` [CIDR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing) block. This block has been reserved by [IANA](https://www.iana.org/) for [private networking](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1918) and is commonly used  for home, office, and enterprise LANs, when globally routable addresses are not required or not available. The mapping in `/etc/hosts` overrides regular DNS lookups, and unless there happens to be a host with the IP address `192.168.1.1` on the local network, the address is unused.

To remedy the situation, remove the following line from `/etc/hosts`:

```
192.168.1.1 www.google.com
```

Comment: May I know why you said the network is 192.168.0.0/16?

Comment: @RonVince The goal of the OPs friend is to block a web site based on its hostname. To do this, he maps the hostname to a _"bogus"_ IP address in the `hosts` file, in this case `192.168.1.1`. Presumably this address was chosen because it is in the `192.168.0.0` - `192.168.255.255` range, which is one of the three [IP address blocks reserved for private use](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1918). Because these addresses have no global meaning, packets with private source or destination addresses should not be forwarded across inter-network links.

Comment: @RonVince Of course, if the OPs laptop happens to be in a LAN which uses addresses from `192.168.1.0/8` block, there might be a host with the address `192.168.1.1` present, which might have unintended consequences. As [you wrote](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/127203/43779), the particular address is the conventional address for the `192.168.1.0/8` network gateway, making it a somewhat unfortunate choice, although the significance of the address is that it would not be used on the global Internet.

Comment: I missed 'result of Ping www.google.com - 100 % packet loss' which makes 192.168.1.1 mapped to www.google.com is obviously not network gateway or host. The fact that OP could surf internet validates that 192.168.1.1 is not network gateway. But no one except the network administrator can know that if 192.168.1.1 is mapped to a MAC address which is probably not online. None of the given information can lead to deduce to what network is being used on the LAN. I understand your reasoning why 192.168.1.1 was used in this case and 192.168.0.0/16 (quite rare).

Comment: @RonVince You are misreading me. I'm **not** saying that the OPs _network_ is `192.168.0.0/16`, nor that it isn't `192.168.1.0/8` (the gateway could be at a different address). _You cannot determine the network from the information provided._ I'm only saying that the significance of the `192.168.1.1` address is that it belongs to a private block, which means that it is _less likely_ that the address would point to a host (although in this particular case it happens to correspond to the conventional gateway address), and certainly not a host on the global Internet.

Comment: Oh, no no. I think I understand you. The significance of 192.168.1.1 is it is private IP address (one of 192.168.0.0/16). My previous comment except the last line is not specifically about your comment, but about the issue in general based on the given information and my mistake to state that 192.168.1.1 is OP's network gateway.

Comment: Exactly! Apparently it was I that misread you thinking that you referred directly to my earlier comment. Your original comment also threw me off a bit since I've been consciously referring to address _blocks_ (i.e. sequences of consecutive addresses), and not _networks_ (i.e. actual assignments of addresses). The terminology is somewhat ambiguous in this regard.

Comment: In my original comment, I really thought you mean 192.168.0.0/16 is the network address. Later on, I realized you what you mean is the IP block. Somehow, you beat me to comment my first comment before I mentioned this. Before I posted the second comment, your comment had been accepted as the answer. Thus, instead of editing or add comment to my answer about the mistake of network gateway, I figured that it was better to include it in my second comment because you had already covered it on the comment to my original comment. The sentence '(quite rare)' may made you think I misread you. (cont..)

Comment: The sentence really means that using 192.168.0.0/16 as one network is quite rare. But when I state 192.168.0.0/16 it really refers to block IP, not network. I tried to make the whole sentence short by combining '192.168.0.0/16' and '(quite rare)' together but it seems like the idea can be misinterpreted. My bad.

Comment: Anyway, IP block by itself is a network. I understood the context of your of your answer in regards to 192.168.0.0/16 when giving attention to the word 'reserved'. The word is the one that clarified what you meant. This may help others about this discussion.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the content of /etc/hosts, www.google.com is set to be the IP 192.168.1.1. It does not matter if you have set your computer to use any DNS servers including Google DNS server. Your computer will check the hostname, e.g. www.google.com, if it matches the hostname on /etc/hosts file first before it request the hostname to be resolved by the pointed DNS server.

As for the solution, remove '192.168.1.1 www.google.com' line on /etc/hosts file and save the edit.